# Is there a scientific significance to Fibonacci numbers in economics?

Tags: fx, quant-trading-strategies, finance-mathematics, quantitative, statistical-finance

I am new to the field and have read popular articles on Fibonacci numbers, but I did not find it grounded in academic research and would love to know if there is a research basis for this and whether the logic behind it can be explained,
Thank you

Comment: In technical analysis, Fibonacci retracements are employed to identify resistances and supports. But I guess that hardly counts as academic research ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what is hardly scientific? If it has a basis and the statistics supporting it are scientific, and if not then it's nothing, what does that mean? Thanks

Comment: I happen to believe in reasonably informationally efficient markets implying that such trading systems do not yield significant excess returns. I don't think there's any evidence that trading based on Fibonacci retracements (or many other technical indicators) is profitable (= significant risk-adjusted returns). Fibonacci trading in particular is very subjective.

Comment: It is "popular", "commonly used", "traditional" but it is not scientific. As KeSchn said there are many Fibonacci levels/ratios and it often seems that the price "came very close" to one of them, and people conclude that "you see, it seemed to work this time". But this is not a proper objective  test.